# How do I do this javascript question about a student greet?

Tags: javascript

```js
var students = ["Brandon", "Daniel"];

var greetStudent = "Hello, ${students[1]}"

for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  greetStudent(students[i]);
}

for (let student of students) {
  greetStudent(student);
}
```

How do I get it to show with console.log `" Daniel"` as it is `${students[1]}`?

I'm a starter in javascript. Please help me, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `greetStudent` as a function and use a template literal instead of a regular string.

```js
let students = ["Brandon", "Daniel"];

const greetStudent = student => `Hello, ${student}`;

for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
  console.log(greetStudent(students[i]));
}

for (let student of students){
  console.log(greetStudent(student));
}
```

Comment: wow thank you I appreciate it. That was quick.

Comment: @DanielDominic Happy to help.

Comment: @Unmitigated I think this is an homework from school, so giving straight answers might not help with learning process :)

Comment: @user3133 Actually, this is not homework from school. It's a project from Frontend Masters.

Answer (score 0):

`greetStudent` has to be a function, not a variable since you are calling it.

```js
const greetStudent = (student) => {
    console.log(`Hello, ${student}`)
}
```